# How can I set the hotspot to the center of a custom cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

I'm using a custom cursor (png image) on a web page using cursor CSS attributes. I'd like to know if I can center the cursor position  (like the cross-hair cursor in Windows) and not using the default top-left position.

One solution will be to hide the cursor and create a div with the custom cursor which will follow the cursor position but maybe someone has a better solution.

Comment: I doubt there is a better (or even different) solution. :]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your cursor is in `.cur` format (only `.cur` and `.ani` are supported in IE), then whichever program you use to create the `.cur` can set the hotspot in the header.

If you're using any other image type, CSS 3 allows the `x` and `y` values of the hotspot to be set:

> ```
> #myEl { cursor: url(mycursor.png) <x> <y>; }
> ```
>
> Supported in:
>
> - Firefox 1.5+
> - Safari 3+
> - Chrome 1+

#### References

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Answer (score 3):

Also you can form your own .cur file using this amazing link `http://www.cursor.cc/`
Not only this the hotspot can also be decided and placed here itself.